# Find a relationship between $f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$ and $f(A)$. Prove it in the general.

Tags: real-analysis

I assert that the relationship between $f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$ and $f(A)$ is $f(f^{-1}(f(A))) = f(A)$. Here is my proof:

RHS: Let $y \in f(A)$. Then there exists an $x$ in $A$ such that $f(x) = y$. $f(x) \in f(A)$ since $y \in f(A)$ and $y = f(x)$. Now, take $f^{-1}(f(x)) \in f^{-1}(f(A))$, which is $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Then, take $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$. Hence, $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$ since $y = f(x)$.

LHS: Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$. Then there exists an $x$ in $f^{-1}(f(A))$ such that $f(x) = y$. Take $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Then take $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$, which is $y \in f(A)$ since $y = f(x)$.

Is this a correct proof of the relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You might have the right idea, but you need to write it better. In particular, you should never write things like $f^{-1}(x)$, because you don't know whether $f$ is bijective. Here's the "LHS" (it's the easiest one):

Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$, this means that there is some $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$ such that $y = f(x)$. But $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is by definition the set of all $x$ such that $f(x) \in f(A)$. Hence $y \in f(A)$.

Comment: My approach was a bit more algebraic, but I think I like yours better. It makes the definitions do all the heavy lifting, thanks!

Comment: So yeah, I am working on the RHS, trying to use definitions. I am pretty stuck, and I am wondering if you can send me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Try to show first that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Comment: Could you give me a hint what the first line in this part of the proof would be?

Comment: Let $x \in A$, then $f(x) \in f(A)$. But $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is the set of *all* $x$ such that $f(x) \in f(A)$.

Comment: Does that imply that  f−1(f(A)) contains A?

Comment: Yes. And of course if $A$ contains $B$, then $f(A)$ contains $f(B)$ and you are done.

Comment: Hmm. Let's see: Let x∈A, then f(x)∈f(A). But f−1(f(A)) is the set of all x such that f(x)∈f(A). This implies that f−1(f(A)) contains A, which further implies that f(f-1(f(A))) contains f(A).

My comment above was more of a guess than a sure answer - can you please explain why it is implied that  f−1(f(A)) contains A. I have a rough idea, but I would like for it to be clearer! Thanks.

Comment: The standard way to prove that $A$ contains $B$ (or that $B$ is a subset of $A$) is to prove that if $x \in B$, then $x \in A$. Here, we show that if $x \in A$, then $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.